# Is there a pre-existing taxonomy of attackers?

Tags: corporate-policy, terminology

When building a security policy (and implementing it) you must know who you are defending against. I would like to use proper terms, if they're already defined. I'm imagining a list such as:

- *Passive attackers* - Those who aren't interested in you specifically but might intercept your data (like the NSA if it doesn't have an interest in you)
- *Uninterested attackers* - Those that aren't interested in you in particular, but are actively testing your defenses. I would classify automated SSH attacks and port scans in this category (looking for easy targets, etc).
- *Active, interested attackers* - People actively trying to break your security to get inside the network. Pentesters or someone you pissed off in IRC.

That's all I have. Is it enough, or is there a level of finnese I've missed? Is there any group of attackers I've completely forgot about?

Comment: [This](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/kdd04.pdf) might be of interest, although a bit too "academic" to fit into corporate policy somehow

Comment: the NSA doesn't have an interest in you, they did try, but its just not working out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of taxonomies already exist. If you're writing and implementing a security policy, following an ISO 27000 nomenclature may prove convenient.

In any case, Wikipedia got a pretty exhaustive list of various standard listing threats to IT infrastructure, of which attackers are only a subset.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_%28computer%29

Answer (score 7):

Check out Intel's Threat Agent Chart:

[image]

Page 8 -> https://communities.intel.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadBody/1151-102-1-1111/Threat%20Agent%20Library_07-2202w.pdf

Answer (score 0):

MISP has a lot of great stuff assembled here:
https://github.com/MISP/misp-galaxy/tree/master/clusters

They have items for botnets, banker malware, exploit kits, ransomware, etc.